# PostgreSQL increase a table's sequence with one query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence, auto-increment

I want to unite the following two queries into one:

```
SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('purchase_orders', 'id');
SELECT setval('purchase_orders_id_seq', 30000);
```

But if I place the upper SELECT into the setval's first parameter I get:

```
SELECT setval(SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('purchase_orders', 'id'), 30000);

ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 15
```

How can I pass on the select's result ("purchase_orders_id_seq") for setval?

EDIT: The reason for this is that; I want to use it like a function where a user only have to enter the table's name and a number to where sequence will be set.

```
FUNCTION set_id_sequence(TEXT table_name, INTEGER sequence);
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the query that is failing.

Comment: What is `pg_serial_get_sequence`? I've never heard of it, and my 9.4 install professes ignorance when asked with `\df pg_get_serial_sequence`. What're you trying to accomplish/fix here, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I edited the question, maybe it's clearer now.

Comment: No, not really. Why do you need to do this in the first place? You shouldn't need to go around setting sequences.

Comment: It's not me who needs this. :) Our client has a sys-admin and he requested that he could separate default data by having their ids starting from 1 and user-created entries with an offset of let's say 10000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to pass a subquery result as a function argument, you need parentheses around it:

```
SELECT setval((SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('purchase_orders', 'id')), 30000);
```

But in this case, the SELECT is redundant; you can invoke the function directly:

```
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('purchase_orders', 'id'), 30000);
```

Comment: YES! That's it! Thank you so much, it was a redundant SELECT. :-)

Answer (score 1):

### General function and automation

All "migration" or "starting database" SQL-script files have some controlled `INSERT` sequence before to use `serial` automation, so it need a simple command to say "ok, back to standard operation".

This generic operation is `SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM schemaName.tableName`...
and, as @NickBarnes showed above, the basic `setval()` operation is `setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('schemaName.tableName', 'idName'), NEWVAL)`, so putting all together we automate the task.

#### 2018's standardization proposal

```
CREATE FUNCTION std_setmaxval(
    p_tname text,
    p_id_name text DEFAULT 'id'
) RETURNS SETOF bigint AS $f$
BEGIN 
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE  format(
    'SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence(%L,%L), COALESCE((SELECT MAX(%s)+1 FROM %s), 1) , false)'
     ,p_tname, p_id_name, p_id_name, p_tname
    );
END
$f$ LANGUAGE PLpgSQL;
```

See [quotation problem/solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/141680/90651) to optimize. **Please review this answer, it is a Wiki (!)**. And update the [standard *snippet* proposal](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Category:Snippets).

---

PS: I not understand why postgreSQL not offer a native function for this task... Well, I not see at [*info*'s Guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) or [*sequence*'s Guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html).

Answer (score 0):

Change Sequence owner:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE purchase_orders_id_seq OWNED BY purchase_orders.id;
```

Set sequence value:

```
SELECT pg_catalog.setval('purchase_orders_id_seq', 30000, true);
ALTER TABLE ONLY purchase_orders ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT
    nextval('purchase_orders_id_seq'::regclass);
```

Comment: It's almost there! But the SET DEFAULT will not accept pg_get_serial_sequence('purchase_orders', 'id') for the ::regclass. So who wants to modify the purchase_orders table still have to know the 'purchase_orders_id_seq' identifier. What I had in my mind was a function like: set_id_sequence(TEXT table_name, INTEGER sequence). Thus a person calling this function only have to know the table's name.